# Keep getting floating point exception in prime number c++ program

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that takes a user integer and determines whether or not the integer is a prime number. However, when I try to enter a number I get a floating point exception. Why is that? I made an array in order to go through every number up until the integer to check its divisibility Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int n)
{
    int arr[n];
    if (n == 1 or n == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if (n % arr[i] == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
             return true;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int user_input;
    cout << "Enter an integer to test if it's prime: ";
    cin >> user_input;
    bool value = isPrime(user_input);
    string true_false;
    if (value == 1) {
        true_false = "true";
    }
    else {
        true_false = "false";
    }
    cout << true_false;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats the array for? Just divide (modulo) by `i`.

Comment: `int arr[n];` is not valid C++, and arrays in C++ are indexed starting at zero.

Comment: Where do you expect the values in the `arr[]` array come from, the ones you're comparing to (ignoring, for the moment, the fact that variable length arrays are not standard C++)? Which part of the shown code is responsible for initializing all the values in the array? What is`n` supposed to be? A number, or an index into this array, which is not even getting initialized to anything?

Comment: *Why is that?* The zeroth level answer is "because your program divides by zero" (even though it's integer division, the exception is still a floating point one).

Comment: By the way, 1 is not a prime.

Answer (score 0):

The fatal exception occurs in the line `if (n % arr[i] == 0) {`. This array points to uninitialized memory, which will occasionally contain 0 resulting in a divide by zero error. Thanks to [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m). for pointing out my error.

Using C idiom such as `int arr[n];` where `n` is not a know constant at compile time is going to result in common C programming issues, like this. C++ has features that can be used which avoid these problems. I recommend you study and use modern C++.